# reverse three digit subtraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cannot get this. How does it work? Like what is the concept in this?

Imagine $895 - 598$:

- Step 1. $8 - 5 = 3$    (I got $8$ and $5$ from the hundreths place in the numbers I am subtracting)

  Step 2. $3 × 100 = 300$  ($100$ is because $8$ and $5$ were originally from the hundreths)

  Step 3. $300 - 3 = 297$ (Subtract the answer from step 2 from the answer from step 1.)

  Final result. $297$ is the answer to $895 - 598$.

Comment: Please use MATHjAX (HERE IS THE TUTORIAL): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please don't use all-caps in comments (or in general), it comes off as rude and it seems like you're shouting. As for the question, what are you asking? A proof as to why it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the number be $a \cdot 10^2 + b \cdot 10 + c$, the reverse is $c \cdot 10^2 + b \cdot 10 + a$

Hence subtracting them gives us $$(a-c)\cdot 10^2-(a-c)$$

In the first step, you computed $a-c$.

In the second step, you computed $(a-c)\cdot 10^2$

In the third step, you computed $(a-c) \cdot 10^2-(a-c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,
$$895-598=\left(8\times10^2+9\times10^1+5\times10^0\right)-\left(5\times10^2+9\times10^1+8\times10^0\right)=\left(8\times10^2-5\times10^2\right)+\left(9\times10^1-9\times10^1\right)+\left(5\times10^0-8\times10^0\right)=3\times10^2+0\times10^1+\left(-3\times10^0\right)=300-3=297$$